# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: in ChatterBot

Tags: pip, chatterbot

I tried to install ChatterBot by "pip install chatterbot", but I am getting errors even I have Visual C++ 14.0 and wheel but it giving me an error that "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required".

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ohv9rtd4\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'

How I can resolve this.

```
    C:\Users\reddy>pip install chatterbot
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.2.19.tar.gz (5.7 MB)
Collecting pint>=0.8.1
  Using cached Pint-0.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (197 kB)
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ohv9rtd4\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (277 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-49.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (789 kB)
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Processing c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\f2\d4\16\366223ea944794b7a8ff2194de44033ceef210e8d8bb76fe79\wasabi-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (181 kB)
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached numpy-1.19.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (13.0 MB)
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.48.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: preshed, thinc, blis
    Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-z4f9oqdq'
         cwd: C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d8cukpfl\preshed\
    Complete output (21 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_pop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\counter.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\maps.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\counter.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\maps.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    running build_ext
    building 'preshed.maps' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for preshed
    Running setup.py clean for preshed
    Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\thinc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\thinc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5xbha81r'
         cwd: C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d8cukpfl\thinc\
    Complete output (166 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\check.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\describe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\i2v.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\loss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\rates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\t2t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\t2v.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\v2v.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests
    copying thinc\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests
    copying thinc\tests\strategies.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests
    copying thinc\tests\test_api_funcs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests
    copying thinc\tests\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests
    copying thinc\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests
    copying thinc\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_affine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_beam_search.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_check_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_difference.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_feature_extracter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_hash_embed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_imports.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_linear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_loss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_mem.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_ops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_pooling.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_pytorch_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_rates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\test_rnn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    copying thinc\tests\unit\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\unit
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\test_affine_learns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\test_basic_tagger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\test_batch_norm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\test_feed_forward.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\test_mnist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\test_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\test_roundtrip_bytes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\test_shape_check.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    copying thinc\tests\integration\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\integration
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\linear
    copying thinc\tests\linear\test_avgtron.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\linear
    copying thinc\tests\linear\test_linear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\linear
    copying thinc\tests\linear\test_sparse_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\linear
    copying thinc\tests\linear\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\tests\linear
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\mem.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\pooling.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\train.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\vec2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\vecs2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\vecs2vecs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\_lsuv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\hpbff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\load_nlp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\visualizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\affine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\attention.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\batchnorm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\convolution.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\difference.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\elu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\embed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\encoder_decoder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\feature_extracter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\feed_forward.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\function_layer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\hash_embed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\layernorm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\maxout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\multiheaded_attention.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\relu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\resnet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\rnn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\selu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\softmax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\static_vectors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    copying thinc\neural\_classes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural\_classes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\_vendorized
    copying thinc\extra\_vendorized\keras_datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\_vendorized
    copying thinc\extra\_vendorized\keras_data_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\_vendorized
    copying thinc\extra\_vendorized\keras_generic_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\_vendorized
    copying thinc\extra\_vendorized\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\_vendorized
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\wrapt
    copying thinc\extra\wrapt\decorators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\wrapt
    copying thinc\extra\wrapt\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\wrapt
    copying thinc\extra\wrapt\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\wrapt
    copying thinc\extra\wrapt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra\wrapt
    copying thinc\linalg.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\structs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\typedefs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\cpu.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\linalg.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\structs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\typedefs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\compile_time_constants.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\linalg.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\structs.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\typedefs.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc
    copying thinc\linear\avgtron.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\features.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\linear.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\serialize.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\sparse.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\avgtron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\features.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\serialize.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\sparse.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\avgtron.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\features.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\linear.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\serialize.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\linear\sparse.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\linear
    copying thinc\neural\ops.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\optimizers.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\_aligned_alloc.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\cpu.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\ops.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\ops.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\optimizers.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\neural\_aligned_alloc.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\neural
    copying thinc\extra\cache.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\eg.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\mb.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\search.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\cache.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\eg.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\mb.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\search.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\cache.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\eg.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\mb.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    copying thinc\extra\search.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\thinc\extra
    running build_ext
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for thinc
    Running setup.py clean for thinc
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1rnwoq7k'
         cwd: C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d8cukpfl\blis\
    Complete output (21 lines):
    BLIS_COMPILER? None
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
    copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
    copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
    copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
    copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
    copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
    copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
    copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
    running build_ext
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis
  Failed to build preshed thinc blis
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for preshed: started
      Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-syxf24gn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ohv9rtd4\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ohv9rtd4\overlay\Include\preshed'
           cwd: C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d8cukpfl\preshed\
      Complete output (6 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      building 'preshed.maps' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d8cukpfl\\preshed\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-syxf24gn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ohv9rtd4\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ohv9rtd4\overlay\Include\preshed' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\reddy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ohv9rtd4\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Venkata Subba Reddy Edula,

As you can see, it asks for Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 14.0.

So, in order to install it, you can visit this site,

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Download the required Version of the software and run the code again. It should work.